# using pipe and dplyr to append item to list

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, magrittr

I have a dataframe mappedAttModel and a list called features. I want to append the piped item. I'm getting Error object (.)not found.

````
for (i in 1:length(features)){
 mappedAttModel %>%
 dplyr::filter(.data$att == features[[i]]) %>%
 dplyr::select(.data$model) %>%
 purrr::pluck(1,1) %>%
 #append to the list
 ###l1 <- append(l1,.)
 }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `purrr::map` to return a list instead of growing one with the for loop. Something like this should work

```
l1 = 
  purrr::map(1:length(features),
             function(i) {
               mappedAttModel %>%
                 dplyr::filter(.data$att == features[[i]]) %>%
                 dplyr::select(.data$model) %>%
                 purrr::pluck(1,1)
             }
  )
```

Note there are several variations of map depending on the type of output you want.